# How to convert an array of integers to an integer

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a ruby array that looks like this:

```
[nil, 3, 4, 2]
```

I would like to convert it to an integer, like so:
`342`

Is this possible, if so, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: If roundtripping via string is allowed, then it's trivial (as shown by Andrey). Try implementing it without using string. Good exercise.

Comment: If your array can contain `nil`s, then what should arrays like `[nil, nil, nil]` be converted to? (And if your answer is `0`, should `[3, 2, nil, 1]` be converted to `321` or `3201`?)

Comment: That's a valid point you're asking @TomLord, in my case though, this array is an output from a function I wrote. The manner in which I wrote this function is that it will always return to me an array in a form of `[nil, 1]` or `[nil, 1, 2]` or `[nil, 3, 4, 2]`. And in a case where I have `[nil, 0, 1]`, I would want to have `1` or `104` for `[nil, 1, 0, 4]` . I'm not sure if this is what you were asking?

Comment: Could you get the arrays:`[nil]` and `[0]`? Do you want to convert them *both* to `0`?

Comment: There's not really a "wrong answer" here as such; I just wanted to point out that what you're doing is a little bit dodgy if there are non-integers in the array. (Or if there are multi-digit numbers.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[nil, 3, 4, 2].join.to_i
#=> 342
```

Comment: You don't need compact

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
[nil, 3, 4, 2].inject(0){|x, d| d ? (x * 10) + d : x}
# => 342
```

Comment: It may be one of those questions, where it's our moral obligation to _teach_ them to fish, rather than giving them the fish.

Comment: Nice, although I'd use `ary.compact.inject { |x, d| x * 10 + d }` to handle `nil`

Answer (score 1):

when you can not simply follow operation precedence and ruby becomes lispy -))

```
a = [nil, 3, 5, 5]
a.each_with_index.inject(0) { |s, e| s+(e[0].to_i)*(10**(a.length-1-e[1])) }
#=> 355
```

below lines are more a-la-ruby synonyms. thanks to [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) for guidance.

```
a.reverse.each_with_index.inject(0) { |s, (i, e)| s + i.to_i * 10 ** e }
a.reverse_each.with_index.inject(0) { |s, (i, e)| s + i.to_i * 10 ** e }
```

above snippet simply multiplies every element with powers of 10 and sums them.

Comment: yes, you are right, let me fix it.

Comment: You can decompose the array argument using extra parentheses and iterate the elements in reverse order to avoid the `a.length` call: `a.reverse_each.with_index.inject(0) { |s, (i, e)| s + i.to_i * 10 ** e }`

Comment: haven't  tried `reverse_each` before -)) thanks.